# node.js mysql connection connect hang 30+ seconds

Tags: mysql, node.js

why some requests reach timeout when trying to connect? it doesnt happens all the time and i wasnt able to repreduce it.
when the timeout happens, the code execute logging step2 and not step3.

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "xxxx",
    user: "xxx",
    password: "xxx",
    database: "xxx",
    charset: 'utf8mb4'
});

console.log("step2");

con.connect(function (err) {
                    console.log("step3");
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("step4");
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("step5");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: are you running out of connections?  Does the MySQL server have anything it its error log?

Comment: how can i check the mysql server error log? if you are reffering to the `err` variable, nothing inside the connect callback is getting executed so i dont know

Comment: You need to be on the server to access the server error log. It isn't accessible through nodejs connection APIs. There is significance variance depending on MySQL server OS, distribution, version, package origin, server setup, so I'm not going to guess. Its an exercise for you to find or provide previous details and possibilities eliminated.